# How to properly mock navigator.language in Jest?

Tags: mocking, jestjs

What is the correct way to mock `navigator.language` in Jest, so I can test my functions that depend on the browser's locale?

I'm using this, which works, but I wonder if there's a more modern and cleaner way.

```
function setLanguage(language: string) {
  (window.navigator as any).__defineGetter__('language', () => language);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the three argument version of spyOn available in Jest 22.1.0+ you can do:

```
jest.spyOn(navigator, "language", "get").mockImplementation(() => "en-GB");
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname