# Mock the locale used by Number.toLocaleString in jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to write some unit tests on a function that calls `Number.toLocaleString()` with no arguments (which causes it to use the browser's language as the locale).

I need to be able to mock the browser locale used by this function, so I can unit test how it works for different locales.

I tried mocking `window.navigator.language`, but I guess the toLocaleString implementation doesn't directly read this value, so it doesn't work:

```
let windowSpy: jest.SpyInstance;
beforeEach(() => {
  windowSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'window', 'get');
});
afterEach(() => windowSpy.mockRestore());

it('should format correctly (fr-CA)', () => {
  windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
    navigator: {
      language: 'fr-CA',
      languages: ['fr-CA'],
    },
  }));
  const result = 12345678.9.toLocaleString();
  expect(result).toEqual('12 345 678,9');
});
```

The above test fails because it returns en-US format:

```
    Expected: "12 345 678,9"
    Received: "12,345,678.9"
```

What do I need to do to mock the browser's locale for `Number.toLocaleString()`?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/69316374/740553? (because `navigator` is not a plain object, so you can't just mock it as one. Better to _only_ mock the `language` getter)

Comment: I did try it, and it doesn't make a difference. Mocking `navigator.language` just does not seem to affect the locale that `Number.toLocaleString` uses. Maybe the Number formatter's default locale gets instantiated before the mock happens? Or it reads the locale from somewhere else, not navigator.language

Comment: Your example doesn't appear to be a unit test on a function you wrote, it looks like a unit test for Number.toLocaleString.

Comment: The code in my post is just a minimal example of the problem I'm running into. The actual code I want to test indirectly relies on Number.toLocaleString

Comment: Followup: is there a reason you can't just say `.toLocalString("the-name-of-the-locale")`? Because `(1.10).toLocaleString("fr-CA", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 })` works just fine, giving `1,10` (with [a lot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#options) of options that you can pass to further refine the output)

Comment: Hmm thanks for the idea. I guess when the code is running in a browser, calling `.toLocaleString(window.navigator.language)` should probably produce equivalent behavior to `.toLocaleString()`, while also letting me mock `window.navigator.language` to change the behavior in my unit tests, so that should work

Comment: Jest should be using `jsdom` to mock the browser environment, but that specifically should be used from the Node implementation. For details you can [check here](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html). It may or may not return the formatted date depending on the build. So I think your best bet is to spy on the `Number.prototype.toLocaleString` and check if the rendered value is the returned value from the spy